# Rendering Smoke on GPU causes: CUDA error cuCtxCreate: Launch failed

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, gpu, error

So whenever I try to render a smoke simulation on my GPU I'm presented with this error:

[image: CUDA error][image: Rendering]

After receiving this error message I can no longer render anything on this file. I ran a test with only a small amount of smoke in my scene and still received the same rendering error, I have tried turning on experimental and still didn't resolve my issue. Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Smoke in Scene]

Graphics card:
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

[image]

Comment: Maybe related - https://developer.blender.org/T49059. Try loading Blender without interface and checking. As it looks from that thread it might be out of memory error (but you could also provide logs from Blender console window).

Comment: Was having this problem for hours too and finally I've found the solution: http://artificialflight.org/blog/2013/cycles-crash-cuda-tdr-error/ Thanks Julian Herzog!

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend Ignac's suggestion - the TDR setting will mess up many animations if not extended.

As a side suggestion, I would download a program called 'GPU-Z' - blender will often crash before showing the actual amount of memory needed, which in my experience is double the amount stated. EG if you get a crash at 1228 MEM, it's because blender actually needed more than 2400 MEM. I usually see this during the 'Building BVH' stage.

GPU-Z will actually tell you how much memory was being used at the point of the crash. Very handy.

Hope this helps,
Regards, C.